# I cant open my Emulator 'Error Opening Emulator'

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, flutter-dependencies

I am Using Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1

The problem it is throwing :

INFO | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz INFO | added library vulkan-1.dll HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. INFO | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local INFO | Advertising in: C:\Users\Debasis\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_280.ini INFO | Android emulator version 31.2.8.0 (build_id 8143646) (CL:N/A)